# For the 20 minutes cooking time

Tags: prepositional-phrases, numbers, compounds

> Leave the vegetables to steam over the rice for the 20 minutes cooking
> time
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles-espanol/cooking-time

Shouldn't the phrase be "for the 20 minutes OF cooking time"?

Comment: Your version would certainly be more idiomatic in American English.

Comment: It's fine in British English.

Comment: I'm American, and to me it looks fine either way.